# Select Where giving no result

Tags: php, sql, select, where-clause

I want to select one field value from a record where another value in the record matches my specified value.

The "SKU" is unique, it isn't the PK, but it is unique. I select only the one field (Code) from the table, so the variable $gemCode should only contain that 1 value. However on the echo, it either outputs nothing like the below code, or if I do specify the field "$gemCode['Code'] it just spurts "Resource id #8" which I've never seen before.

```
$gemCode = mysql_query("SELECT Code FROM stock WHERE SKU = 'TN-YKJI-ESWB'");

        echo "Gem Code: ".$gemCode."<br>";
```

This code is in a loop, for each line of a file which it'll be taking the SKU value from. Though even though the code has none of the loop in it (variables taken from the file etc) the output it does give, the "Resource id #8" number goes up each loop starting at 8:

```
Gem Code: Resource id #8
Gem Code: Resource id #9
Gem Code: Resource id #10
Gem Code: Resource id #11
Gem Code: Resource id #12
Gem Code: Resource id #13
Gem Code: Resource id #14
Gem Code: Resource id #15
```

I've had issues where before somehow data in my tables have spaces after them so "LIKE '%value%'" was needed, though I've checked and the values in question are don't have this, so its not like I'm looking from values that don't technically exist.

Should also mention I do have:

```
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');         
mysql_select_db('amazondb', $conn);
```

I'm really stumped, I thought it'd just be a simple select where.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks -Tom

Comment: Have you read the documentation on `mysql_query()` AT ALL?  If you have you would have noticed two things: 1) That `mysql_query()` doesn't just return a value ready to be set to a variable and 2) that `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and should no longer be used.

Comment: Sorry for asking a question. Sometimes things are over looked, or god forbid people are new, but thanks to you I still don't know the answer to my simple issue... no wait thats a lie, other people actually helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use mysql_fetch_assoc($gemCode) if you want to database result.

```
$gemCode = mysql_query("SELECT Code FROM stock WHERE SKU = 'TN-YKJI-ESWB'");
$gemArr = mysql_fetch_assoc($gemCode);

print_r($gemArr);
```

But, outsdie of "that's how you do it" you should really look into using [mysqli_](https://www.php.net/mysqli_query) instead of mysql. And if you're up to the challenge of learning [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), you should try and use that (yes, even over mysqli_).

Comment: Also, I know you said SKU will always be unique, but do you have a unique constraint on your table to ensure that is always true?

Comment: You're right, I assumed too much. Sorry. Do "echo $gemArr['Code'];" instead of the "print_r($gemArr);".

Comment: Thanks, it was a silly question in the first place to ask, evident by some people getting a little uppity. I've done what you suggested, and what I needed to do numerous times before, I just over looked the need, brain misfired.

Answer (score 0):

you need to fetch the data.

```
$gemData = mysql_query("SELECT Code FROM stock WHERE SKU = 'TN-YKJI-ESWB'");
$gemInfo = mysql_fetch_assoc($gemData);
    echo "Gem Code: ".$gemInfo['Code']."<br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Complementing the previous answers, [mysql_query()](http://br.php.net/mysql_query) returns a resource, not the string.

As good practice, I suggest you remove the mysql_query from the loop and use "...WHERE SKU IN ('TN-YKJI-ESWB', 'yourSecondKey', ..., 'yourNKey')" and take a look on:

- mysql_result()
- mysql_fetch_row()
- mysql_fetch_array()
- mysql_fetch_assoc()
- mysql_fetch_object()

at [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/index.php) manual.